# Hiding tablix based on scope

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have a report with 4 pages (which contain a myriad of tablix's and subreports).  The last two pages should only show if there is data.  I have each page as it's own group (group names = PAGE1, PAGE2, PAGE3, PAGE4).  I also have a group for pages 3 & 4 (group name = "EXTRA").  I have a parent group containing the report as a whole (group name = "LRSN").

I've been trying to hide pages 3 & 4 based on the presence or absence of data in a Tablix ("Tablix2"), which falls within the group "PAGE3" and parent group "EXTRA".  I have tried hiding rows, tablixes and the group "EXTRA" as a whole.  Seems like that should work, but...no luck.

I've tried hiding the pages at the group, Tablix and/or row levels; I've tried numerous combinations of conditional statements for example:

```
=CountRows("Tablix2")=0; 
=RowNumber("EXTRA")<0; and 
=IIF(CountRows("EXTRA")<0, True, False)
```

I get error messages (such as "The Hidden expression for the grouping "EXTRA" has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function...blah blah".

I've tried mixing up the scopes and containers, but nothing seems to be working.

How should I be writing the conditional statement and at what level (group? tablix?).  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you at first step try hiding page 3 and 4 without any conditions so that you know at least hiding works. If that works then condition can be dealt with.

Comment: So it looks like hiding works at the group level, but not at the tablix level within the groupings.  I'd prefer to hide the groups (which is why I set it up that way bc I thought it would be more manageable).

Comment: did you managed to resolve this?

Comment: No - how do I write the condition?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're on the right track with the `CountRows` and `RowNumber` functions, but I believe you need to count from the dataset, not a specific group or tablix.  If you don't already have a separate dataset for the `Tablix2` that you are using as a parameter for hiding the pages, you should create one specifically for the data in `Tablix2`.  You should then be able to set the visibility on the Tablix level with the following expression.

```
=IIF(CountRows("YourTablix2DatasetHere") > 0, False, True)
```

This expression should hide each Tablix from the desired pages when there are no rows returned from the dataset.

Comment: Aargh - still can't get it to work.  Tablix2 contains 2 subreports.  I set up new datasets in which to check for no rows returned.